# xlwings: pass a variable into formula bar

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to loop over multiple files, creating new formulas for each file as I go. To do that I want to concatenate a string with a variable, then use excel wings create a new formula. To that end I've written this code:

```
file_name=r'[Element_IA_Gross.xlsx]'
equation=r'=SUM(\''+file_name+'Total Immediates\'!$R6:$T6)'
ws.range("O19").value= [equation]
```

If I print the variable `equation` I see what I want in the excel formula bar. However using the above code doesn't work? Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula looks for the workbook in the default location so opens a file search window and waits for the input.
The following works based on why it worked for me by opening both workbooks, adding the formula to 'book1', save 'book1' and then close both books.

```
import xlwings as xw


file_name = 'Element_IA_Gross.xlsx'
workbook = 'Book1.xlsx'

with xw.App() as app:
    wb1 = xw.Book(workbook)
    wb2 = xw.Book(file_name)
    ws = wb1.sheets('Sheet1')

    equation = "=SUM('[" + file_name + "]Total Immediates'!$R6:$T6)"
    ws["O19"].value = equation

    wb1.save(workbook)
    wb1.close()
    wb2.close()
```

-------------Option 2 ----------
This option also worked including the whole path and filename in the formula.

```
import os
import xlwings as xw

path = r'F:\Projects\xlwings_test'
file_name = 'Element_IA_Gross.xlsx'
link = os.join(path, file_name)
workbook = 'Book1.xlsx'

with xw.App() as app:
    wb1 = xw.Book(workbook)
    ws = wb1.sheets('Sheet1')

    equation = "SUM('[" + link + "]Total Immediates'!$R6:$T6)"
    ws["O19"].value = equation

    wb1.save(workbook)
    wb1.close()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this but unfortunately not, the scripts just hangs, any other thoughts? Would have expected the above to work and I tried in something similar.

Comment: Yeah OK, it's probably waiting for you to find the 'Element_IA_Gross.xlsx'. I realise now why it didn't ask me when I did a quick test for syntax is because I had that workbook open while testing. I've updated the answer to show full code for two options that work (for me), so one hopefully would work for you.